# How to select all script nodes containing a specific string

Tags: c#, html, xml, xpath

Suppose I have several script nodes in an HTML document, how would I select all of the ones that contain a particular source value:

```
<head>
</head>
<body>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        blah();
    </script>
</body>
```

What's the proper way to select only script nodes **within the body** which contain a function `blah`?

### Update

<strike>I tried `//script[contains(text(), 'blah')]`, but it didn't work.</strike>

Comment: It can't be as simple as `//script[contains(., 'blah')]`, right?

Comment: I've been trying `//script[contains(text(), 'blah')]` and it wasn't working... is there a way to restrict to only finding script nodes within the body?

Comment: `//script[contains(text(), 'blah')]` *should* work, as well. It would be interesting to know why it does not for you.

Comment: @Tomalak it works with `text()` too, must have had a typo somewhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

//script[contains(., 'blah') should work
the difference between . and text() is that there can be multiple text nodes (in theory), and text() matches a sequence of all of them.

Another possibility is that you have XHTML and you need to bind the XHTML namespace to a prefix, e.g. "h", and say, //h:script[contains(., 'blah')], and how to do that depends on the exact calling environment, e.g. registerNamespace() or something. You need to register the same URI that's in the xmlns="...." in the document, most likely http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml, e.g. like this if you are using XmlDocument in .net:

```
System.Xml.XmlNamespaceManager xmlnsManager =
                 new System.Xml.XmlNamespaceManager(xmldoc.NameTable);

xmlnsManager.AddNamespace("h", "http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml", xmlnsManager);

result = xmldoc.SelectNodes('//h:script[contains(., 'blah')]')
```

Answer (score 0):

What about iterating through each script element using the javascript search function?

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_search.asp

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script'); 

    for (var i = 0; i < s.length; i++) {
        var src = s[i].innerText;
        var result = src.search("blah()");
        if (result != -1) {     
            console.log(src);
        }
    }

</script>
```

The script should go inside the page load logic to process all script elements that occur after this one.

Comment: 1, w3schools is not reliable source of info (see w3fools.com ) 2, question is tagged XPATH, so this is not an answer